# Using plt.text to print calculated values in a plot

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

Hi Is there a way to print values calculated by a script directly into the plot that is being made?

For example say I have a data file that I read in. Then I want to calculate the total number of entries, the sum of the entries, the average and standard deviation. How can I then print these vales right on to the histogram that I then plot?

I looked here http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text, but it was not very helpful. Thanks in advance

Example

```
file = 'myfile.txt'
d = np.loadtxt(file)
C = d[:,3]

S = sum(C))   
avg = np.mean(C)
sigma = np.std(C)
N = len(C)
```

I tried this but it did not work

```
n, nbins, patches = plt.hist(C, 20)
plt.title("My Histogram")
plt.text(0,0, 'Sum of vales ='S  '\n' 'Total number of entries = ' N  
         '\n' 'Avg= 'avg   '\n'   'Standard Deviation = ' sigma)
ply.show()
```

Comment: [Rolled back edit which fixed the syntax problems; for all we know the syntax errors *are* the problem.]

Comment: can you explain what the syntax errors maybe?

Comment: also if I run ``plt.text(0,0, 'Sum of vales =' '\n' 'Total number of entries = ' 
         '\n' 'Avg= '  '\n'   'Standard Deviation = ' )
ply.show() `` it works perfectly

Comment: @Surfcast23 Because Python automatically join two adjacent strings into one string. `'hello' 'world'` -> `'helloworld'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to call `show()` after `plot(...)`

#### Update

I *chat* with OP in comments. It turns out that the problem is `syntax error`. His original code

```
plt.text(0,0, 'Sum of vales ='S  '\n' 'Total number of entries = ' N '\n' 'Avg= 'avg   '\n'   'Standard Deviation = ' sigma)
```

He try to concat string in this way `'some string' variable 'another string'`. He ask me why `'some string'  ' another string'` is OK, because Python automatically join adjacent strings into one single string. In this case, he gets `'some string another string'`, which is a valid python statement.

Comment: I did have plt.show() in my original code . I will edit my question.

Comment: Yes, they are plotted at the left bottom corner.

Comment: Did you assign values to N,S, sigma, and avg and then have them printed in the plot? Because when I try to run it I get a syntax error about `'Sum of values =' S`

Comment: Oops, that is really a syntax error, having no business with `plot`. Try this code `plt.text(0,0, 'Sum of vales = %s\n Total number of entries = %s\n Avg= %s \n Standard Deviation = %s' % (S, N, avg, sigma))`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much for your help. Would you mind explaining for myself as well as others who are not as well versed why what you did worked? Because to be honest, in my opinion, unless you have a lot of experience with coding and python/numpy the doc's are pretty useless

Comment: @Surfcast23 I update my answer. I think you have too less experience with Python ;-)